# Go, модули для парсинга

Tags: golang

Подскажите пожалуйста как ускорить парс текстовых файлов на Go, может есть модули какие. Сейчас у меня парсит регуляркой, как видно из профайлера это бутылочное горлышко.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

grep как-то парсит быстро, значит можно делать быстрее

Comment: Лучше сами регулярки конечно показать. Но даже сейчас видно, что Вы используете "просмотр назад". А он может тормозить. Обычно лучше просто переписать регулряки

Comment: Добавлю к вопросу коллеги свой: напишите пример файла, который парсите.

Comment: "просмотр назад" - это оглядывания? Go их же не поддерживает.
Вот регулярка:
(?si)[,]CALL(?:.*?)p:processName=(?P<DB>[^,]+)(?:.+?)Context=(?P<Context>[^,]+)(?:.+?)MemoryPeak=(?P<Value>[\d]+)

Comment: вот другая с частью файла
https://regex101.com/r/jTTVV6/1/

там просто несколько шаблонов регулярки

Comment: Вот это поворот. Похоже, оглядывания [используются-таки](https://tip.golang.org/src/regexp/backtrack.go), но только в ограниченных контекстах. Посмотрим, как можно ускорить ваш вариант.

Comment: Вам видимо легче использовать пакет `strings`. [Вариант](https://play.golang.org/p/5cKf5LGpzDJ) для нахождения исключений более чем в 10 раз быстрее.